# Entity Framework Code First create db from models

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to use entity framework to build the database and I need some help with the models:

The models are: Company, Departments, Users, TaskType1, TaskType2, TaskType3

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
         this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string CompanyName { get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public string Phone { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set;}

}

public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public virtual Company Company { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public Company()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set;}
    public string FullName { get; set;}

    public virtual Department Department { get; set;}               
}


public class TaskType1
{
    public TaskType1()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public int Priority { get; set;}        
}

public class TaskType2
{
    public TaskType2()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public int Priority { get; set;}    
    public double EstimatedCosts { get; set;}
}

public class TaskType3
{
    public TaskType3()
    {

    }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public int Priority { get; set;}    
    public bool IsDone { get; set;}     
}
```

the reason I need to have TaskType1, TaskType2, TaskType3 as tables is because there are different types of tasks (different data/fields is needed).

How can I connect my task types to the Company and to the Department and Users so I can get results like:

- all tasks per company X
- all tasks assigned to department z from company x
- all tasks assigned to user w from department z from company x

P.S. The task types have common and different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish relationships between your models. For example, to get all tasks per company X, you would need a companyID column in each of your Tasks tables and have that be a foreign key to the Company table. Then you can set up a navigation property in the Company model:

```
public virtual ICollection<TaskType1> TasksType1 { get; set; }
```

*You use an ICollection here because a company can have multiple tasks...if each company could only have one task, you could do something like:*

```
public virtual TaskType1 TaskType1 { get; set; }
```

This lets you access the tasks like so:

```
companies = db.Companies.Include(i => i.TasksType1);
```

Have you checked out the Contoso University tutorial? It has a good introduction to establishing hierchical models and the associated relationships.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

(This is the MVC version, there is also a WebForms version of the tutorial if you are so inclined)